# Função em jQuery Ajax não retorna o Valor

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo uma conversão de Moeda Brasileira (Real) para a Moeda Chinesa (Yuan). Estou utilizando a API do site: `https://free.currencyconverterapi.com` . Ao fazer a depuração no navegador, consigo ver que a função Ajax com a solicitação API está funcionando, porém quando retorna a variavel `valor` na penúltima linha do código, o valor retornado não está sendo o valor convertido e sim o valor original, segue o código:

```js
function converterreal(valor){
   
   var moeda = 0;
   var valor = valor;
   var valorconvertido = 0;
   
   $.ajax({
     url: 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=BRL_CNY&compact=ultra&apiKey=873041c527593ec7e31e',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(data) {
    moeda = data.BRL_CNY;
    console.log(moeda);
     valorconvertido = (moeda*valor); 
     
     function formata(v){
      return parseFloat(v).toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});
     }
     //document.write(formata(valorconvertido));
     
     valor = formata(valorconvertido);
     
     
     }
     
   })
   return valor;  
  }
    
    var testevalor = converterreal(400);
    $("#valorreal").html(testevalor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>O valor em real é: <span id="valorreal"></span> BRL<br>
```

Comment: Vc tá chamando a função em tempo de execução, mas o Ajax é assíncrono e não devolve o valor do `success` na mesma hora.

Comment: @Sam como posso corrigir isto?

Comment: Fazer tudo dentro do success, quando a API retornar os valores.

Comment: @Sam esta função vai retornar valores em varias `div`, eu tentei colocar tudo dentro do sucess, além de não ter retornado nenhum valor, não sei como faria para usar a mesma função em outra `div id`

Answer (score 1):

Caiu na pegadinha do [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).

O que acontece e que q parte do ajax demora um pouco mais pra executar, quando chega no seu `return valor;` o request ainda esta sendo processado.

Esse trecho `valor = formata(valorconvertido);` so executa bem depois de a funcao ja ter sido executada, e meio confuso no inicio eu sei.

Imagina que o `$ajax` roda em paralelo, mesmo depois de a sua funcao ja ter terminado o request continua "vivo".

Procure estudar alguns termos como `callback`, `async`, `await`, `async function`.

Por hora para resolver o seu problema seria algo assim

```js
function converterreal(valor){
 var moeda = 0;
 var valor = valor;
 var valorconvertido = 0;
 
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=BRL_CNY&compact=ultra&apiKey=873041c527593ec7e31e',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
   moeda = data.BRL_CNY;
   console.log(moeda);
   valorconvertido = (moeda*valor); 
   //document.write(formata(valorconvertido));
   
   valor = formata(valorconvertido);
   $("#valorreal").html(valor);
  }
 })
}
    
//nao e uma boa pratica declar uma funcao dentro da outra
function formata(v){
  return parseFloat(v).toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});
}

converterreal(100)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>O valor em real é: <span id="valorreal"></span> BRL<br>
```

Comment: Ao clicar em Executar,  o valor convertido não está sendo exibido.

Comment: @Wendell provavelmente por nao esta cainda no `success`, isso ta acontecendo por que atingiu o seu limite de request na api. Esta retornando essa resposta `{"status":400,"error":"Free API limit reached."}`

Comment: sugir editar a pergunta e tirar o parametro `apiKey` da URL

Comment: Teria alguma forma da requisição API retornar só o valor da moeda? (Por exemplo, 1 Yuan é igual a 0,56 real) Assim utilizaria este valor que retornasse em outras fórmulas sem precisar requisitar a API

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque você está dando `return` antes do valor ser setado pela função, já que ela é assíncrona. Uma forma de resolver o problema seria alterar o valor do campo dentro da função, ou adicionar as funções `done` e `fail` ao seu ajax para que elas retornem o valor apenas quando ele for setado.

Método 1:

```
function converterreal(valor){
    var moeda = 0;
    var valor = valor;
    var valorconvertido = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=BRL_CNY&compact=ultra&apiKey=873041c527593ec7e31e',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            moeda = data.BRL_CNY;
            console.log(moeda);
            valorconvertido = (moeda*valor);    

            function formata(v){
                return parseFloat(v).toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});
            }

            //document.write(formata(valorconvertido));

            $("#valorreal").html(formata(valorconvertido));
        }
    });      
}
```

Método 2:

```
function converterreal(valor){
    var moeda = 0;
    var valor = valor;
    var valorconvertido = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=BRL_CNY&compact=ultra&apiKey=873041c527593ec7e31e',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    })
    .done((data) => {
        moeda = data.BRL_CNY;
        console.log(moeda);
        valorconvertido = (moeda*valor);    

        function formata(v){
            return parseFloat(v).toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});
        }

        //document.write(formata(valorconvertido));

        return formata(valorconvertido);
    })
    .fail(() => {
        return 0;
    });      
}
```